# How to fill table/grid manually

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am using Vaadin 8 and I want to make some sort of confusion matrix. I was wondering if I can fill the values of the table/grid manually according to the cell position, instead of data provider.

```
referenceTable.addColumn(reference -> String.valueOf(reference.getId())).setId(REFERENCE_ID).setCaption(REFERENCE_ID).setMinimumWidth(100).setMaximumWidth(200);
referenceTable.addColumn(reference -> String.valueOf(reference.getTitle())).setId(TITLE_COLUMN).setCaption(TITLE_COLUMN).setMinimumWidth(100).setMaximumWidth(500);
```

I don't have any specific model which I can use.

Something like this, I want
[image]

Comment: Check this Grid with HashMap instead of POJO example, it is for newer Vaadin version, but Grid API is almost the same in Vaadin 8: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map

Comment: There is Vaadin 8 example of Grid using List as its type also here, which makes possible to use index to access the data for the column: https://github.com/tatulund/gridflip

Comment: That works. Can you please post it as answer. I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Also, how can I implement StyleGenerator for each of the cell. I am using StyleGenerator, but it complains about not applicable for list<String>

Comment: I added StyleGenerator to github.com/tatulund/gridflip and there seems not to be an issue about that.

Comment: I was using wrong iterator, instead of "index". Works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Grid in Vaadin is typed with POJO type bean and the API is optimized for that use case. However you can potentially use Grid with any valid type parameter. You can e.g. use List or HashMap<String,String> just to name few.

In GitHub there is Vaadin 8 example of [Grid using ArrayList](https://github.com/tatulund/gridflip), which makes possible to use index to access the data for the column. The full code is too extensive to be featured here. The example contains also demonstrator for style generator.